# Mocking HttpClient when new instance is created inside the constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I have the following class that instantiates a new HttpClient instance  in the constructor:

```
public class Posts
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;

        public Posts(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = new  HttpClient();
        }

        ...
}
```

I've followed [this](https://dev.to/gautemeekolsen/how-to-test-httpclient-with-moq-in-c-2ldp) blog to mock HttpClient for my test. But it's not working, since in the example, they are passing in HttpClient as a param in the constructor, whereas I am instantiating a new one every time. This results in the mock getting overwritten with what I have in the class.

The mock from the blog:

```
var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
var response = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StringContent(@"[{ ""id"": 1, ""title"": ""Cool post!""}, { ""id"": 100, ""title"": ""Some title""}]"),
};

handlerMock
    .Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync",
        ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(response);
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object);
var posts = new Posts(httpClient); // passed into constructor when the class instantiated
```

My questions are:

1. How can I stop my class from overriding the mock?
2. Should I put HttpClient as a param in the constructor, as shown in the blog? If so, what's the benefit of it over my way?

Answer (score 3):

Your subject class is not using the mock or any client that is injected into it since the constructor initializes and tightly couples to it's own instance.

Instead the class should explicitly inject the client

For example

```
public class Posts {
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public Posts(HttpClient httpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    //...
}
```

This now allows the dependency to be changed as needed when testing, and in production code you will configure your application to inject the actual client.

Ensure that `HttpCLient` in registered with the DI container used by the application.

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

so the DI container knows how to resolve it when building the object graph for dependent classes

Comment: Tried this but got this error `Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate 'WebApi.PostsController`

PS. I'm actually using HttpClient in my controller

Comment: @blankface You need to make sure that you added `HttpClient` to the service collection so the DI container know how to resolve it.

Comment: There's no IHttpClient for  HttpClient so how should I inject it as a service?

Comment: @blankface refer to documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#additional-resources also check out the additional resources.